# Kepler problem: Time spent by a comet inside the orbit of the Earth

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, solar-system, celestial-mechanics

This is was an exercise on my exam of classical mechanics which I couldn't solve. The question goes as follows:

Imagine a comet moving on a parabolic orbit in the plane of the earth. Take the earth's orbit as a circle with radius R and the sun in the centre. The shortest distance that the comet comes to the sun is $\beta R$ with $\beta<1$. So the comet is on the inside of the earth's orbit for a certain time. Prove that the time the comet spends in the circle is
$$
\Delta t = \frac{1}{3\pi}\sqrt{2(1-\beta)}(1+2\beta) \times \text{year} 
$$

Hints:
$$
\int \cos^{-4}x\,dx= \tan{x}+ \frac{\tan^3{x}}{3} + C,
$$
$$
\cos{2x}=1-2\sin^2{x}
$$

I tried calculating the path of the comet with the polar equations of a hyperbola, but I have no clue how to solve this.

Comment: *Imagine a comet moving on a parabolic orbit* ... *I tried calculating the path of the comet with the polar equations of a hyperbola.* A hyperbola is not a parabola.

Comment: Wouldn't you have to start with defining the comet's parabola?

Comment: Use a constant. Your end result will then contain it (but that doesn't show in the solution you quoted...)

Comment: Since it is parabolic, there is an extra condition, i.e. total energy E(t) = 0. This condition together with the nearest distance r = beta R is able to find the velocity at the nearest point. The nearest distance and its velocity fix the equation of parabola y = c x^2.

Comment: @ytlu $y=cx^2$ means the comet crashes into the sun.

Comment: The equation should be $y=cx^2+\beta R$. I think

Comment: I should say the parabola, y = c x^2 - beta R, for the sun to sit at (0,0), Otherwiase, the sum will be at (0, beat R).

Comment: @ytlu *i.e. total energy E(t) = 0* Huh? The total Hamiltonian is constant but the comet has KE all the time.

Comment: @Gert Yes, For the case E(r->inf) < 0, the orbital is a elliptic, means that the planet has finite radiall distance. For E(r=inf) >0, the orbital is hyperbolic, and the critical condition E(r=inf) = 0 is the parabolic. In a math point of view, the planet can never reach r=infinity..

Comment: @JakobBoonen Yes, $y=cx^2+\beta R$, I think so too.

Comment: On trying to get the polar equation I get $r=\frac{sin\theta \pm \sqrt{sin^2(\theta)-4c_1c_2cos^2(\theta) \beta R}}{2c_1cos^2(\theta)}$ where c1 and c2 are constant. c2 is +-1, depening on the sign of $\beta R$.

This gives a problem when I try to get the result $r=\beta R$ at $\theta =\pi/2$,cause cos(pi/2)=0...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting excercize. Kepler's Third Law for the orbit of the Earth gives us
$$
T^2_\text{e} = \frac{4\pi^2}{k}R^3\tag{1},
$$
with $k=GM_\odot$ (ignoring the mass of the Earth). The Kepler orbit of a parabola in polar coordinates is
$$
r = \frac{h^2}{k}\frac{1}{1 + \cos\theta},\tag{2}
$$
where $h$ is the specific angular momentum. The closest approach occurs at $\theta=0, r=\beta R$, from which be obtain
$$
h^2 = 2\beta Rk\tag{3}.
$$
Let's call $\theta=2x$. At $r=R$,
$$
1 + \cos 2x_\max = 2\cos^2x_\max = 2\beta.\tag{4}
$$
From
$$
h = r^2\dot{\theta},\tag{5}
$$
we get
$$
\sqrt{2\beta Rk}\text{d}t = \frac{(2\beta R)^2}{(1+\cos\theta)^2}\text{d}\theta.\tag{6}
$$
Eliminating $k$ using $(1)$, and integrating, leads to
$$
T = \frac{2T_\text{e}}{\pi}\int_0^{x_\max}\frac{(2\beta)^{3/2}}{(1+\cos 2x)^2}\text{d}x.\tag{7}
$$
The rest is straightforward.

Comment: The quation 1 is irrelavant. You can start with r = c / (1+ cos theta), and fix the constant c at r = beta R. and theta = 0.

Comment: I shouldn't say eqaution (1) is irrelavant. We need it to convert the unit to year in the final result..

Answer (score 1):

[image: Comet, Earth]

I don't have a full solution but would attempt the following in Cartesian coordinates.

1. determine the coordinates of points $A$ and $B$, from:

$$x^2+y^2=R^2$$
and:
$$y=cx^2+\beta R$$

So that:

$$\frac{y-\beta R}{c}+y^2=R^2\tag{1}$$

The two roots of $(1)$ give the coordinates of points $A$ and $B$

2. determine the path length between $A$ and $B$ (with integration, say $\Delta L$).
3. determine the velocity-time function $v(t)$ (I'm not sure how to go about this).

Now if the total time traveled between $A$ and $B$ is $\Delta t$, then:

$$\int_0^{\Delta t}v(t)\text{d}t=\Delta L$$

Comment: Your equation didn't match with the figure. Looking your figure, it should be y = beta R - c x^2.

Comment: The velocity will be found from the condition that total energy = 0, for case of a parabolic orbital. The total energy is a constant indenpend of time.